# How to fill List<IInterface> from Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to reuse a list for certain tables. Hence, the model classes implement the `IDocument` interface like this:

```cs
public partial class databaseTable : IDocument
```

If I try fill a list of this interface:

```cs
public List<IDocument> DocumentList { get; set; }
```

with this code:

```cs
DocumentList = dbcxt.databaseTable.ToList();
```

or

```cs
DocumentList = dbcxt.databaseTable
    .Select(x => new ITegDbDocument // didn't really expect this to work...
    {
        Id = x.Id,
    })
    .ToList();
```

I get a compiler error CS0029

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'

Is there a way to fill a list of type interface from a database table using EF Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `dbcxt.databaseTable` is `DbSet<databaseTable>` (where `databaseTable` implements the `IDocument` interface) - you can just provide explicit generic type parameter for `ToList`:

```
DocumentList = dbcxt.databaseTable.ToList<IDocument>();
```